# Can't unblock rfkill internal wifi, but usb wifi doesn't work either

Tags: wireless, rfkill

Sometimes the internal wifi on my Amilo Pi 2515 is disabled and can't be enabled using the hardware switch (in BIOS too), since the device is a bit dated and this only occurred recently, I'm assuming a hardware issue.

So I tried using a USB wifi dongle instead, but that gets disabled too.

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`rfkill unblock all` does not change anything.

Is there some way to ignore rfkill altogether?

Comment: hard block means either hardware is disabled by switch or driver not present

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to ignore rfkill since it's diagnostic and utility, but not internal yo your card/driver.  Saying "can't I just ignore rfkill" is a bit like saying "can't I just not get oil changes on my car".  In both cases they're not directly related to the key in the ignition, getting charge to your sparkplugs, or getting fuel to the engine.

It's not a direct simile since rfkill doesn't really contribute to your driver operation like an oil change does, but it should get the point across.